# Correct interpretation of "on y porte les valeurs" in a mathematical context

Tags: sens, traduction, mathématiques

I'm attempting to translate the following sentence, but the proper translation for the word "porte" is eluding me:

[image]

The best I can come up with is:

[image]

The translation "carries" doesn't quite make sense to me given the text, so I'm thinking my translation is bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Porter des valeurs dans une formule* means to replace the variables in a formula by some values.

I would translate without passive voice eg "...as it should, when d?, d? and d? take the values (73), (77) and (80)"

Or, if you want to be closer to the original, "...as it should, when therein substituting the values (73), (77) and (80) for d?, ..."